# I Can't create a new line inside textbox within a for loop

Tags: c#

I have been trying to create a new line after each divisor is printed, but it hasn't worked with any of the methods. I changed the multiline attribute of the text box to true and tried `\r\n` and then the `Environment.NewLine` but it doesn't work, the number are always printed in one line without spaces.

```
private void button_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int divisor, inserted;

    inserted = Convert.ToInt32(txt_input.Text);

    for (divisor = 1; divisor <= inserted; ++divisor)
    {
        if (inserted % divisor == 0) 
        {
            txt_output.AppendText(Convert.ToString(divisor).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about WinForms or ASP.NET?

Comment: Also _divisor_ is an integer converted to a string. It doesn't contain any newline to replace. Just use _divisor.ToString() + Environment.NewLine_ without any kind of replace

Answer (score 0):

```
 txt_output.AppendText(Convert.ToString(divisor).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));
```

??? so try

```
txt_output.Text = txt_output.Text+Convert.ToString(divisor)+"\r\n";
```

AppendText adds to the end, which seems like what you want, but thats whats preventing you from going to the next line, also dont think you need to replace, if you want to clear the textbox before setting it again just call:

```
txt_output.Text="";
```